# Are global memory loads/stores going through caches in devices with compute capability 1.x?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I'm using an old Tesla GPU C1060, G80 architecture. I'm wondering if data requested by threads from the global memory address space is cached, as it happens in more recent architectures.

Comment: The L1/L2 cache hierarchy was introduced in GPUs with compute capability 2 and above. Your device has a compute capability of 1.3 and global memory accesses can not be cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CUDA Programming Guide, Section G.3.1](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capability-1-x):

> The local and global memory spaces reside in device memory and are not cached.